# iOS swift JSONSerialization does not maintain original sorting order of JSON data received from API

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, nsjsonserialization

I'm developing an iOS application where I request items from an API.  The API has a result sorting field that I set to "itemDistance".  This is great because if I run a query in a zip code and there's a total of 900 items that are found, the API will sort all 900 items by distance.

When I examine the original JSON string, I can see that the items that the API gave me are perfectly sorted by location distance.  So, here's the issue:

Before I present those results in the table view, I have to do some stuff, which you're all aware. One of the first and main things that I do is to apply JSONSerialization to the perfectly sorted raw data.

```
do {
   let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObj(with: data, options: [])

   guard
      let jsonDictionary = jsonObj as? [String:Any],
      let myDictionary = jsonDictionary["items"] as? [String: Any] else {           
        ...
            }

...
```

This works great and I'm able to populate my table view and see all the items, but the problem is that they are not in the correct order by distance as I shown in the original JSON string. If I print jsonDictionary, the original order by distance is gone.  JSONSerialization re-sorts the data by item ID so I lose all the original sorting by distance that the API did.  I don't want them sorted by ID.  How do I preserve the order of the items by distance so it matches the same order as the original JSON string?

Here's a sample of what the original JSON String looks like.  As you can see they are all sorted by location distance.

The only thing I can assume why this is happening is because the API is sending me "items" in a dictionary rather than an array. Is it not maintaining the distance order because "items" is in brackets, not square brackets, which means it's in a dictionary and not an array? I tried to convert jsonObject and jsonDictionary to arrays myself, but it still doesn't work.

I need to maintain all the pre-sorting by distance that the API does because if there's hundreds of items, the API will pre-sort those hundreds for me.  Since I'm not fetching all hundreds at once and only 25 at a time, I cannot sort each group individually manually because there's no way of guaranteeing that the next group will contain all larger distances than the previous group. I'm not using any third party libraries.  I tried SwiftyJSON to see if that would work and it didn't.  It still re-sorts them by ID because SwiftyJSON uses JSONSerialization behind the scenes.

```
{
    "queryStatus": "good",
    "queryMessages": {
        "plainMessages": [],
        "otherMessages": []
    },
    "totalItems": 610,
    "items": {
        "20513”: {
            “itemID": "20513",
            “itemDistance": 0
        },
        "81144”: {
            “itemID": "81144",
            “itemDistance": 0
        },
        "81142”: {
            “itemID": "81142",
            “itemDistance": 0
        },
        "81456”: {
            "itemID": "81456”,
            "itemDistance": 0
        },
        "36891”: {
            "itemID": "36891”,
            "itemDistance": 17
        },
        "35142”: {
            "itemID": "35142”,
            "itemDistance": 17
        },
        "75146": {
            "itemID": "75146",
            "itemDistance": 17
        },
        "40937”: {
            "itemID": "40937”,
            "itemDistance": 19
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: A dictionary's order is *undefined*. The API should send an array of dictionaries. Using dictionaries like this is an antipattern. This is the work of an array.

Comment: Dictionaries have no order. If you want order you need an array.

Comment: Eric and Maddy, what you're saying is the conclusion I came to.  The only way to get an array then is to have the API send it to me in an array format, correct?  Like Eric mentioned, an array of dictionaries.  I asked them and they said they will not make the change.  They said it's the key on the objects that are causing the sort issue.  Is that true?  Is it the keys causing this issue or the fact that they are sending me a dictionary and not an array?

Comment: A dictionary is an unsorted collection, if they care about sorting they should have returned an array. However you always have the possibility to parse the dictionary to an array yourself, or just parse to dictionary and convert the dictionary to an array and then sort the array.

Comment: Simon, parsing it to an array is what I'm trying to figure out how to do. The problem with this is that once I apply JSONSerialization and it converts the original JSON string to a dictionary, it loses all pre-sorting order that I want to maintain.  So if I then take that new dictionary and try to convert it to an array, it's not going to have the original order. Since I'm fetching 25 items at a time, I don't think I'll be able to do this since I'd only be creating an array for a batch of 25 so there's no way to guarantee that the next group of 25 has larger distances then the first group.

Comment: You could always make an array of the `items` dictionary then sort the items yourself by the `itemDistance` property. This would be a bit of an antipattern but since the API won't change... you don't have much choice. One way or another you will have to sort the items yourself, because the dictionary's order will never be preserved in JSON or in Swift.

Comment: Eric, great idea, but the only problem I see with this is that it only deals with my batches of 25 at a time.  What I mean by this is I'd only be sorting 25 items at a time by their location distance.  What happens when I scroll down my table view and bring in the next set of 25...there's no way to guarantee that this next set contains all larger locationDistances than the first group of 25.  This is why I really wanted to maintain the pre-sorting that the API did for me since my queries can bring back hundreds of items.

Comment: But the way the API is made doesn't allow you to do that... unless you cheat. Sort the 25, keep them in an array, show them. Get the next 25, add to the previous ones, sort the whole thing, then display. Etc. This is horrible, I know, but given your API limitations I don't see another way.

Comment: Eric, I agree.  It looks like that's the only way to do it.